# Proof by exhaustion: all positive integral powers of two end in 2, 4, 6 or 8

Tags: proof-writing

While learning about various forms of mathematical proofs, my teacher presented an example question suitable for proof by exhaustion:

> Prove that all $2^n$ end in 2, 4, 6 or 8 ($n\in\mathbb{Z},n>0$)

I have made an attempt at proving this, but I cannot complete the proof without making assumptions that reduce the rigour of the answer.

> All positive integral powers of two can be represented as one of the four cases ($k\in\mathbb{Z},k>0$, same for $y$):
>
> - $2^{4k}=16^k=10y+6$
> - $2^{4k+1}=2*16^k=10y+2$
> - $2^{4k+2}=4*16^k=10y+4$
> - $2^{4k+3}=8*16^k=10y+8$

The methods of proving the four cases above were similar; here is the last one:

> $8*16^k=8*(10+6)^k$
>
> Using binomial expansion,
>
> $8*(10+6)^k=8*\sum\limits_{a=0}^k({k \choose a}10^k6^{k-a})$
>
> All of the sum terms where $a\neq0$ end in zero, as they are a multiple of $10^k$, and therefore, a multiple of 10. The sum term where $a=0$ is $6^k$, because ${k\choose0}=10^0=1$. Therefore, the result of the summation ends in six.
>
> Assuming that all positive integral powers of six end in six, and eight multiplied by any number ending in six ends in eight, all powers of two of the form $2^{4k+3}$ end in eight.

That conclusion doesn't seem very good because of the two assumptions I make. Can I assume them as true, or do I need to explicitly prove them? If I do need to prove them, how can I do that?

Comment: It is not true, since $n\ge 0$ explicitly allows $n=0$ and $2^0$ ends in $1$.

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a typo; the original question only stated that $n>0$. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need to prove them.

- If $6^n=10k+6$, then $6^{n+1}=60k+36= (6k+3)10+6$, which also has $6$ in the units digit. Use induction.
- If $n=10k+8$, then $6n=60k+48=(6k+4)10+8$, which also has $8$ in the units digit.

---

There is an easier way of "exhaustion" in my opinion: proof by contradiction. For example, assume that $2^n=10k$. This would mean that $5|2^n$ (five divides the power of two), an impossibility, so no power of two can end in $0$. For the rest (units digits 1, 3, 5, 7, 9), show that even numbers (that is, the multiples of two) are closed under addition and subtraction (for example $2n-2m=2(n-m)$), so if e.g. $2^n=10k+1$, then we would expect $2^n-2(5k)$ to be even, but 1 is not a multiple of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I do prove the two assumptions, is my proof otherwise valid?

Comment: @Delan: Note that, since you need induction to prove the statement about $6^n$, you might as well use induction on the original problem, which allows a far simpler proof.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought to approach the proof that way. I'll give it a go; thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If the decimal expansion of $2^n$ is $$10^m d_m + 10^{m-1} d_{m-1} +\cdots + 10d_1 + d_0$$ where $0\leq d_i \leq 9$ (ie the $d_i$ are the digits of the expansion), then we can write $$2^n=10k+d_0$$ where $$k=10^{m-1}d_m + 10^{m-2}d_{m-1}+\cdots + d_1$$

Therefore, $d_0=2^n-10k$, implying that $d_0$ is even (why?), and hence $d_0\in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$.  The argument given by anon knocks out the possibility that $d_0=0$ (no power of 2 can be a multiple of 10).  Thus, $d_0\in \{2,4,6,8\}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ mod $10,\:$ the powers of $\:2\:$ repeat in a cycle of length $4,\:$ starting with $2,\:$ since

$$\rm  2^{K+4} = 2^K(1+15) = 2^K + 30\cdot2^{K-1}\equiv\: 2^K\ \ (mod\ 10)\quad for\quad K\ge 1$$

Now it suffices to prove by induction that if $\rm\:f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N = \{1,2,3\ldots\}\:$ then

$$\rm  f(n+4)\: =\: f(n)\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  f(n)\in \{f(1),\:f(2),\:f(3),\:f(4)\}$$

Informally: once a cyclic recurrence begins to loop, all subsequent values remain in the loop.

Similarly, suppose there are integers $\rm\:a,b,\:$ such that $\rm\: f(n+2)\ =\: a\:f(n+1) + b\:f(n)\:$ for all $\rm\:n\ge 1.\:$ Show that $\rm\:f(n)\:$ is divisible by $\rm\:gcd(f(1),f(2))\:$ for $\rm\:n\ge 1$.